# How to build a sentence based on tags

Tags: tags, array

I try to build a complete sentence based on tags as follows:

**This is a sentence with tag1, tag2 and tag3.**

My code is:

```
{% set topics = entry.topics.first %}

{% for topic in entry.topics.offset(1) %}
    {% if topic != entry.topics.last %}
       {% set topics = topics ~ ', ' ~ topic %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<p>This is a sentence with {{ topics }} and {{ entry.topics.last }}.</p>
```

My problem is that the if clause does not work. The results is always:

**This is a sentence with tag1, tag2, tag3 and tag3.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it'll be easier and more efficient to achieve that if you use the loop functionality instead of querying the actual tags. I think this code does what you want:

```
{% set topics = '' %}

{% for topic in entry.topics %}
    {% set topics = topics ~ topic ~ (loop.index < loop.length-1 ? ', ' : loop.index < loop.length ? ' and ') %}
{% endfor %}

<p>This is a sentence with {{ topics }}.</p>
```

Comment: You can also use `loop.last` to trim that logic down even further.